# Is making a restoration point on a new laptop a must-do thing?

Tags: drivers, performance, system-restore, windows-backup, setup

According to [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dx9BGn4MivJw&ved=2ahUKEwjmh_uek9fzAhVf_7sIHbs3DqAQwqsBegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1NI6n8uRHIa0_s52LXS4j9), I should do a restoration point of the system before any systems' and drivers' updates and app installation, so I can revert to this state later when needed. It even recommends setting up the laptop without WiFi in order to avoid that.

Is the same thing as [this](https://sassytownhouseliving.com/the-importance-of-creating-system-restore-points-on-your-pc/)? If not, how are they different?

I'm quite reticent about the claim that updates can slow down my system and make my drivers incompatible with my hardware. Is that a thing? Updates are supposed to improve security and performance, aren't they? Plus I've found other articles that encourage updating as a early setup step...

Comment: Im not sure this is on topic, and Im certainly not wading through Youtube videos.   Updates not only can, BUT ARE LIKELY OVER TIME to slow your system.  Buggy drivers are a thing  but it really depends on how mainstream your hardware is.  Updating early us good from a security point if view, but not a stability one. If you update during setup and everything turns to custard, you loose little doing a reinstall. On a NEWLY installed device Id argue a restore point is not critical

Comment: Its not must do, but you are well advised to do so.

Comment: Restore Points can be helpful, but I've found that having a *complete disk image* is *far* safer. Before any update, be sure you have a reliable image to roll back when the update makes the machine unusable. There are long list of updates that have caused *serious* issues, such as deleting user files: https://www.howtogeek.com/658194/windows-10s-new-update-is-deleting-peoples-files-again/

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes I would create a restore point before attempting updates and installation. Sometimes major patches and drivers can contain bugs. Usually due to rushed validation or poor QC before launch. It may become necessary to use system restore to put Windows back to the way it was before you ran the updates. This will save you time in the long run if you ever do encounter system instability after an update.

What the video is showing appears to be creating a system image. Which you can reinstall your operating system from if the worst happens. Most laptops come from the manufacturer with a recovery partition on the hard drive or ssd that you can reinstall from. A system image can be stored externally though so in the event of a drive failure you're still covered.

Generally yes updates do improve performance and security, but as technology moves forward, component drivers can get left behind. A driver that worked fine on Windows 7 might not be compatible with Windows 8.1 or 10. You may have noticed that Windows 11 wont install properly without TPM 2.0 on the pc. It is important to make sure that the hardware you hae will work with the latest updates. When it comes to Windows, generally you'll be okay unless you have some obscure hardware like an old tv tuner card.

Updates can also slow down your system, but it's ,pre of a storage hog than anything. Bring up disk cleanup in Windows, and then click clean up system files. You may find you have several gigabytes of data being taken up by windows update log files and cached files. On top of that, updates can change registry entries in Windows leaving behind old .dll files that are unused or depreciated. I've always used CCleaner to help me clean these files up. Just be careful playing with the registry. If you use CCleaner, it will ask you to back up the registry before cleaning it so if something does happen you can restore the registry in safe mode.

Comment: To expound upon my answer. I recently had an issue with a wifi card driver. It would not connect to my 5ghz network at home even though Windows said there were no driver updates. Installing the manufacture driver fixed the issue and I havent had a problem since. Also be aware, out of date drivers can also cause issues with Windows Update as well.